# Getting HTML 5 download attribute to work on an <a> tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, download

I'm trying to create dynamic links that can download gifs. Here's the snippet in jQuery

```
    var gifDownload = $("<a class='download'>").text("Download");
    gifDownload.attr("href", results[i].images.fixed_height.url);
    gifDownload.attr("target", "_blank");
    gifDownload.attr("download", "");
```

It opens up to a new page and I can view the gif. But it doesn't download. What have I missed?

Comment: This piece of code works just fine for me [**JSfiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/6cea17tg/1/)

Comment: It does open up to a new tab and it can be viewed. However, it doesn't download when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

[`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download) isn't a boolean property like `checked`. It needs to be non-blank (the filename to suggest for the download) in order to trigger download behavior. So:

```
gifDownload.attr("download", "image.gif");
```

Comment: @szewah - Don't know what to tell you. If I take your code, make the change above, add `gifDownlod.appendTo(document.body)`, and use an HREF that refers to an image, it works -- in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, basically anything that supports the `download` attribute.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I have no idea why it's not happening for me but will keep trying.

Comment: @szewah - Does the browser you're using support the `download` attribute? Are you sure you applied the change correctly? Are you sure the link you're clicking is the one the code relates to? Those are the only kinds of things I can think of at this point.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome and  have tried it across Safari and Firefox too. The link is set to the right one. I'm going to look through the code again to see if I've missed anything.